# Telerik Asp.net Skin doesn't work offline (No Internet Connection)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

When i add a **radButton** for example to a web page (**ASP.Net**) and give it a **skin** and run the web page,

if i am connected to internet then it shows the **skin very well**.

[image: With Skin Showed]

But if i am not connected to internet then **it doesn't show the skin**.

[image: Skin Not Showed]

obviously it downloads something.

**How to make it works offline (Without Internet) ??**

***This is the Design code***

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager id="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Put your JavaScript code here.
    </script>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Skin="Web20" Text="RadButton">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check web.config file for Telerik CDN settings:

```
<add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
<add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
```

and remove them to enable local css and js files.